# Как импортировать несколько модулей в main.ts Angular 2

Tags: angular2

Есть файл `main.ts`

```ts
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Как можно подключить несколько независимых модулей? Допустим у меня есть `AppModule` и я хочу импортировать еще один модуль.

Как это сделать ?

Спасибо !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Angular 2 может быть один главный загрузочный модуль (root module) и множество дополнительных модулей (feature modules). Дополнительные модули импортируются в главный через декоратор @NgModules. В файле в котором объявлен AppModule (app.module.ts ?) нужно прописать примерно следующее:

```
import { FeatureModule } from './feature.module'

@NgModule({
    imports: [ FeatureModule ]  
})
export class AppModule { }
```